# gwan: vhost with underscore does not work

Tags: dns, webserver, vhosts, g-wan

Who can explain or having the same experience of the following gwan behaviour:
whenever the name of a vhost has the underscore character,
it can not be reached. gwan will jump to show the root host.
I am using ubuntu 12.04 and always keep updated.
gwan version is 4.1.25.
the CPU is P9300.

Comment: G-WAN listeners use the underscore to separate the IP address and the port number, see: http://gwan.ch/faq#listener so you should NOT use an underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be frank, I don't know much about `gwan`. But, in general, DNS only supports alphanumeric characters (with possible `-`, but only in the middle of the name).

Note that underscore is not in permitted DNS characters list. Many Windows host have underscore in host name, and sometimes IIS servers with such hosts may even work, but it is not supported configuration.

I would think that `gwan` knows about this and does not accept such name as valid name, jumping to your default root host as a backup.

Right solution is to NOT use underscore in any DNS name. You can replace it with `-` (minus) instead.